# Wildcard SSL Cert and Client Authentication

Tags: tls, windows

I have a wildcard SSL certificate (from GoDaddy.com) deployed to several Windows 2003 servers. I used IIS management console to import the certificate. The problem is that only one of these servers enables the certificate for client authentication. As a result, our custom application can access SOAP service only on a single server.

Question: what can I do to enable client authentication on other servers?

Answer (score 1):

Client authentication in SSL is not correlated with whatever is in the *server's* certificate. That the server certificate is wildcard or not has no bearing on whether client authentication will be used or not.

Client certificates will be used only if the server asks for them. Then, the server must be able to *validate* the certificate (make sure that the certificate is genuine, and comes more or less directly from a trusted root), and then to extract a notion of identity from what is in the certificate. In the IIS / Active Directory world, this is called *mapping*. See [this page](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/clientcertificatemappingauthentication) for some details.